# Incorrect syntax near using

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables as:

```
Salesperson
1)ID
2)Name
3)Age
4)Salary

Customer
1)ID
2)Name
3)City
4)IndustryType

Orders
1)Number
2)Order_date
3)cust_id
4)salesperson_id
5)Amount
```

Here is the problem: find the largest order amount for each salesperson and the associated order number, along with the customer to whom that order belongs.

While implementing this

```
Select salesperson_id,Numbers As ordernum,Amount
from dbo.Orders As Ord  Inner Join 
(
Select salesperson_id,Max(Amount) as MaxOrder
from dbo.Orders
group by salesperson_id
) as TopOrder
on TopOrder.salesperson_id = Ord.salesperson_id 
where TopOrder.MaxOrder=Ord.Amount
```

but it shows an error:

```
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Ambiguous column name 'salesperson_id'.
```

Comment: What is that `Using` supposed to do? There is not a `Using` keyword in TSQL as far as I know.

Comment: @Jamiec  sir if i try to use the above code it still shows an error.

Comment: Now, its a different, and straightforward error. You have more than 1 `salesperson_id` fields (once in the `Orders` table, once in the `TopOrder` subquery). The select doesnt know which one you want. (PS. you dont need to call me sir;))

Comment: @Jamiec FYI, `USING` is part of the [`MERGE` syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx). That doesn't explain why it was originally part of this question, of course :)

Comment: @Pondlife - of course it is. silly me. I actually used it yesterday so quite how I didnt figure that out is anyones guess.

Answer (score 1):

You have two salesperson_id in your query, one in the table Orders and one in the subquery TopOrder.

Best practice is always to qualify the field name with the table name or alias.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if sql server supports the using keyword.  The only db I know that does is redbrick.  You might have to change

```
using (saleperson_id)
```

to

```
where toporder.salesperson_id = orders.salesperson_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select sp.Name, od.Numbers, Max(od.Amount)
from SalesPerson as sp left join Orders as od  on sp.ID = od.salesperson_id
Group By sp.ID
having od.Amount = Max(od.Amount)
```

This query will help you list all the sale person name and oder number of order with maximum amount
Try this and feedback me whether it helps you or not

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Select Ord.salesperson_id,Numbers As ordernum,Amount
from dbo.Orders As Ord  Inner Join 
(
Select salesperson_id,Max(Amount) as MaxOrder
from dbo.Orders
group by salesperson_id
) as TopOrder
on TopOrder.salesperson_id = Ord.salesperson_id 
where TopOrder.MaxOrder=Ord.Amount
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select p_orders.salesperson_id,number as 'OrderNum',amount from p_orders
INNER JOIN
(
select salesperson_id,MAX(amount) as 'MAXORDER' from p_orders group by salesperson_id 
) as TopOrderAmountPerPerson
ON TopOrderAmountPerPerson.salesperson_id=p_orders.salesperson_id 
and p_orders.amount=TopOrderAmountPerPerson.maxorder
```